How can I install the R package R4ClinicalTrial?
I want to install the package from https://rdrr.io/github/zhuob/R4ClinicalTrial/
install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("zhuob/R4ClinicalTrial")

failed with the following message:
Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub:
  HTTP error 404.
  Not Found

  Did you spell the repo owner (`zhuob`) and repo name (`R4ClinicalTrial`) correctly?
  - If spelling is correct, check that you have the required permissions to access the repo.

because there is no repository https://github.com/zhuob/R4ClinicalTrial/.
The code for the package can be found at https://rdrr.io/github/zhuob/R4ClinicalTrial/f/
How can I install this package without the GitHub repository?
Thanks, and best wishes,

You may start with contacting the package author. No high hopes, but he may explain what did happen.

Please show the exact error message that you got, e.g. copy-paste into your question
